# Procurar texto em uma String como um "like"

Tags: c++, string, algoritmo, comparação, c++11

Quero fazer uma busca de texto, como as que faço em MySQL. Ex: LIKE "9%4"

Tentei implementar um `find_if()`, mas sem sucesso.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n;
   string a;

   cin >> n;

   while(n--)
   {
        cin >> a;
        if(a.find("35") != string::npos)
            cout << "-" << endl;
        else if(a.find("190") != string::npos)
            cout << "?" << endl;
        else if(find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), "9*4") != a.end())
            cout << "*" << endl;
        else
            cout << "+" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Consigo percorrer toda a *string* manualmente e procurar pelo "9*4"<sup>pode ser qualquer número</sup>, mas acredito que deve ter uma maneira mais inteligente de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
if (a[0] == '9' && a[a.size() - 1] == '4')
```

Se quiser deixar fácil para aceitar padrões com mais de um caractere:

```
auto patternBegin = "9";
auto patternEnd = "4";
if (a.size() > patternBegin.size() && a.size() > patternEnd.size() &&
    equals(patternBegin.begin(), patternBegin.end(), a.end()) &&
    equals(patternEnd.rbegin(), patternEnd.rend(), a.rbegin()))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Like.cpp).

É claro que se precisar de algo mais complexo precisará de um algoritmo mais sofisticado. Este caso tem um padrão no começo e outro no fim, mas poderia ter vários padrões espalhados pela *string*, teria que tratar tudo isto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, no primeiro código código que você postou, se a entrada fosse 94 ele entraria nele também, não entraria?
Esqueci de mencionar também que só haverá um número entre o 9 e 4.
Provavelmente terei de varrer a array inteira mesmo hehe

Comment: Eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Se só pode ter um caractere é bem diferente do que está na pergunta. Aí é simples, basta ver se o tamanho da *string* é 3 também.